# Why does is.vector() return TRUE for list?

Tags: r

I'm an R beginner.  Browsing the R documentation, I stumbled upon this sentence `?is.vector`: 
*"If mode = "any", is.vector may return TRUE for the atomic modes, list and expression."*

I'm just curious - why?  All of the documentation I've read states that lists and vectors are two different data types.  Is there some deeper R datatype concept I'm not getting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A list is (in most cases) itself a vector.  From the help files for `?list`: *"Most lists in R internally are Generic Vectors, whereas traditional dotted pair lists (as in LISP) are available but rarely seen by users (except as formals of functions)."*

This means you can use `vector` to pre-allocate memory for a list:

```
x <- vector("list", 3)
class(x)
[1] "list"
```

Now allocate a value to the second element in the list:

```
x[[2]] <- 1:5

x

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[3]]
NULL
```

See `?list` and `?vector` for more details.

Comment: This explains why the function returns why it does. It doesn't explain why the language is why it is. Anyone have any insights on that?

Answer (score 11):

See the [R Internal Structures](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#R-Internal-Structures) section (specifically section 1.1.1) of the [R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html) manual.  A list (in the sense you're speaking of) is a `VECSXP`, a type of vector.

Comment: @Quant Guy: You don't need to learn the internals to use R, but it's useful if you want to "look under the hood".