# What's the reason behind the disagreement between behavior of lists and matrices (as vectors) in R?

Tags: r, data-structures

My question is regarding different behavior of lists and matrices when seen as vectors in R. I wanted to understand the hierarchy of data-structures in R from the following sequence of code, but have come out more baffled than enlightened.
On the surface the first part of my question on vectors and lists was partially answered at stackoverflow.com/questions/6032772/ However, "under the hood" it is unclear why doesn't the same rule applicable to matrices? This question is supported by a complicated looking function (which was, with all due respect, a part of an example used for teaching functions to "beginners" in R programming in a popular course). Please read until the end, I will appreciate help in clarifying these basics. Here is the sequence:-

Create a vector

```
test<-1:3
```

Check the obvious

```
is.vector(test) 
[1] TRUE
```

Convert it into a list

test<-as.list(test)

Check the obvious

```
is.list(test)  
[1] TRUE
```

But! The object is still a vector.

```
is.vector(test) 
[1] TRUE
```

This gives the impression that every list is a vector. This is confirmed by:-

```
test<-list(1,2,3)
is.vector(test) 
[1] TRUE
```

From the preceding findings the expectation for the matrix was the same

```
test<-1:3
test<-as.matrix(test)
```

Which is clearly not the case

```
is.vector(test) 
[1] FALSE
```

I was further confused by the output of the following "complicated looking, does nothing much" function just created for the sake of demonstrating type-matching of arguments. This function should expect a vector but doesn't throw an error if given a matrix. Do the same rules not apply to data-types when being passed as arguments to functions?

```
 makeVec<-function(x=numeric(0)){


        set<-function(y){
            x<-y    
        }
        get<-function()x

        return(list(get=get,set=set))
    }
```

Create a "vector"

```
my_vec<-makeVec(x=matrix(1:9,nrow=3,byrow=T))  
my_vec$get()

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

!!!!!!!!!!! NO ERROR ??????????

To further clarify

```
is.vector(numeric(0))
[1] TRUE
is.vector(matrix(numeric(0)))
[1] FALSE
```

The last lines show that a matrix of numeric(0) is not a vector. Where are the missing links that I am unable to comprehend at the moment. Please help.

Comment: What is your function `makeVec` supposed to do?  It does nothing useful, as far as I can tell. It's a very complicated way of returning the input.

Comment: Since you've concluded that all lists are vectors, I wonder if the following will add to the confusion: `is.list(data.frame(1)) #TRUE` vs `is.vector(data.frame(1)) #FALSE`

Comment: From the help for `?is.vector`: "*is.vector returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes other than names. It returns FALSE otherwise.*"

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032772/why-does-is-vector-return-true-for-list

Comment: Thanks Andrie, I have edited the question as it is only partially answered by the previous posts.

Comment: Why do you think that your function `makeVec` would expect a vector and throw out an error if given a matrix?