# When does is.vector() return true?

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R. While reading documents, the following sentence confuses me.

> is.vector() does not test if an object is a vector. Instead it returns TRUE only if the object is a vector with no attributes apart from names.

The [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032772/why-does-is-vector-return-true-for-list) about why does is.vector() return TRUE for list might be a good reference.

When does `is.vector()` return true?

Answer (score 3):

Some examples for different data types.

```
x <- list(
  "integer vector"   = integer(),
  "numeric vector"   = numeric(),
  "character vector" = character(),
  "logical vector"   = logical(),
  "complex vector"   = complex(),
  "raw vector"       = raw(),
  list               = list(),
  expression         = expression(),
  factor             = factor(),
  pairlist           = pairlist(),
  "numeric matrix"   = matrix(1),
  "character matrix" = matrix("a"),
  data.frame         = data.frame(),
  formula            = y ~ x,
  "function"         = identity,
  call               = call("identity", 1),
  name               = as.name("a"),
  null               = NULL,
  environment        = new.env()
)
vapply(x, is.vector, logical(1))
##    integer vector   numeric vector character vector   logical vector 
##              TRUE             TRUE             TRUE             TRUE 
##    complex vector       raw vector             list       expression 
##              TRUE             TRUE             TRUE             TRUE 
##            factor         pairlist   numeric matrix character matrix 
##             FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE 
##        data.frame          formula         function             call 
##             FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE 
##              name             null      environment 
##             FALSE            FALSE            FALSE
```

The results for `factor` and `list` are not entirely intuitive, so be careful with those.  Often you want `is.atomic` rather than `is.vector`.

Answer (score 3):

> `is.vector()` does not test if an object is a vector. Instead it returns `TRUE` only if the object is a vector with no attributes apart from names.

The quote means exactly what it says. *Why* it says what it says is more subtle.

All R objects are associated with a list of "attributes", viewable with `attributes()` (for the entire list) with `attr()` (for individual attributes). In fact, the class of an object is really just a special attribute that generic (S3) functions use to determine which method to use.

This property tends to be "quiet" in most cases, but is visible with the output of the `na.omit()` function (try `x <- c(1, NA); y <- na.omit(x); print(y)` to see how this could look). Here, `y` has one attribute, `na.action`, which itself is an object with an attribute, `class`. Assign that attribute to a separate object with `z <- attr(y, "na.action")` and look at its attributes with `attributes(z)` and then `attr(z, "class")`.

When a `class` attribute exists, R uses it to overwrite the class of the underlying object; in this case the `omit` class overrides the internal `integer` class. Try `attr(z, "class") <- NULL; class(z)`. Note that this is the same result as directly writing `class(z) <- NULL`.

Now assign z with `z <- attr(y, "na.action")` again. Try `is.vector(z)`. Then remove its class with `NULL` again and try `is.vector(z)` again. Hopefully this should make it clear what `is.vector` checks for. The fact the `class` attribute has a special use in method dispatch is irrelevant. In fact, you could do the same thing for `y`: try `is.vector(y)`, `is.vector(x[!is.na(x)])`.

The reason for this criterion is that many objects in R that don't look or act like vectors are stored internally as vectors. Matrices are in this category. Try something like `x <- matrix(1:4, 2); dput(x)`. You'll notice that `x` is saved internally as the *vector* `1:4`, with a special attribute `.Dim`. This attribute is hidden and inaccessible; try `attr(x, ".Dim")`.

This is all documented somewhere in the R manual (which is where I first saw it), but I can't remember what section.