# What's the difference between a list and a vector whose mode is list?

Tags: r

Title essentially says it all. I'm having trouble figuring out the difference between initializing a vector with `vector(mode="list")` and a list with `list()`.

There are some minor differences in the signatures, `list()` can take `value` arguments or `tag = value` arguments whereas `vector()` cannot.

And then there's the following quote from the `list()` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/list):

> Almost all lists in R internally are *Generic Vectors*

So is there any actual difference beside the fact that lists can be initialized with tags and values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say they're the same:

```
identical(list(),vector(mode="list", length=0))
## [1] TRUE
```

(see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032772/why-does-is-vector-return-true-for-list) about the confusing fact that a list *is* a vector in R: usually when R users refer to "vectors", they actually mean *atomic* vectors ...)

In my experience the most common use case for `vector(mode="list",...)` is when you want to initialize a list **with length>0**. `vector(mode="list",10)` might be a little more expressive than `replicate(10,NULL)`. If you want to create a length-0 list I can't see any reason to use `vector()` instead of `list()`.